# How To Get Docs Between Two Date (Different field )

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, adonis.js

I have a collection name leave 
When A Employee apply for leave then create a doc with From and To date
 in this format

```
"slots": [
            ObjectId("5c9b5281a2f04a75c6ed77d1")
        ],
        "start_date": ISODate("2019-04-29T00:00:00.308+05:30"),
        "end_date": ISODate("2019-04-29T00:00:00.308+05:30"),
        "user": ObjectId("5cc6d732faad3318b39b80f8"),
        "status": NumberInt(1),
```

When i am run query on collection with this query

```
user: { '$in': [ 5cc6d732faad3318b39b80f8 ] },
  start_date:
   { '$gte': 2019-04-29T18:30:00.000Z },
  end_date:
   { '$lte': 2019-04-29T18:30:00.000Z  }
```

With Same **Start And End Date** Then Query is Not return any document

I can't understand what happened with  this query

when i am run this query **with different start and end date** it's work

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired and worked fine.
Please check your format of date and id in user.

DB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc81bc3767421415293994d"),
"slots" : [ 
    ObjectId("5c9b5281a2f04a75c6ed77d1")
],
"start_date" : ISODate("2019-04-28T18:30:00.308Z"),
"end_date" : ISODate("2019-04-28T18:30:00.308Z"),
"user" : ObjectId("5cc6d732faad3318b39b80f8"),
"status" : 1
}
```

Query

```
db.collection.find({user: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5cc6d732faad3318b39b80f8") ] },start_date:{$gte:ISODate("2019-04-28T18:30:00.308Z")},end_date:{$lte:ISODate("2019-04-28T18:30:00.308Z")}})
```

Returns the doc

Comment: problem in Date format ,Which format is good for mongodb (i am using moment)

Comment: Save as ISODate.  I thinj its better.

Comment: Which Date Format Use in "2019-04-28T18:30:00.308Z" because of i am format date using moment js